# How do I call custom Django Model Manager from Class Based View?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I would like to use a customer model manager that manipulates a field but does not save to the database. How do I call the model manager function named "with_counts()" in the sample code below.

Is it possible to call it from my view or my templates?

```
    LEVEL = [
        ('Pro', 'Professional'),
        ('Int', 'Intermediate'),
        ('OK', 'Competent')
    ]

    Languages = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Years = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    Proficiency = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=LEVEL, default="Competent")


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.Languages} Level: {self.Proficiency}'


    #Do not save to data base. 
    def with_counts(self):
        return self.years * 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods):

> A custom Manager method can return anything you want. It doesn’t have to return a QuerySet.

So in that you are right you can just call that as a normal function in your view like this:

views.py:

```
class your_view(View):
 def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
   counts = YourModal.objects.with_counts()
   # do something with counts
```

models.py:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
  objects = models.YourManager()
```

managers.py:

```
class YourManager(models.Manager):
 def with_counts(self):
    return self.years * 10
```

Comment: This explanation is great. I realize now there are several ways to do this.  Do you know of any resources that give interesting examples of the get method in class based views. I don't get much from the Django docs on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `@property` to your model:

```
@property
def with_counts(self):
    return self.Years * 10;
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/glossary/#term-property and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property for further details.

P.S. you should use lower-case model field names.